# Tracking iOS installs - Google Analytics Property ID for app + web

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to set up link with utm's to track app installs from Apple App Store. In iOS Campaign Tracking URL Builder is requirement to enter Google Analytics Property ID in UA-XXXX-Y format. In the Account Explorer I cannot see Property IDs for web + app, only for classic websites views. I can search for 'property id' in google analytics, but it shows in different 9 digits format which is unacceptable in URL Builder. What shall I do? Thank you for your help!

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?